# JQuery & Echarts: Cannot read property 'getProgressive' of undefined

Tags: html, jquery, echarts

I encountered a strange error when using Jquery and echarts: Cannot read property 'getProgressive' of undefined.

My code went like:

```
<!--
    THIS EXAMPLE WAS DOWNLOADED FROM https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=scatter3d-scatter&gl=1
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
    <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5/dist/echarts.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var dom = document.getElementById("container");
      var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
      var app = {};

      var option;
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://b565a3a9-9a56-458a-97cd-273fbcb46dfe.mock.pstmn.io/data",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(data);
          var sizeValue = "57%";
          var symbolSize = 2.5;

          option = {
            tooltip: {},
            grid3D: {
              width: "50%",
            },
            xAxis3D: {},
            yAxis3D: {},
            zAxis3D: {},
            grid: [
              { left: "50%", width: "20%", bottom: sizeValue },
              { left: "75%", width: "20%", bottom: sizeValue },
              { left: "50%", width: "20%", top: sizeValue },
              { left: "75%", width: "20%", top: sizeValue },
            ],
            xAxis: [
              {
                type: "category",
                gridIndex: 0,
                name: "App",
                axisLabel: { rotate: 50, interval: 0 },
              },
              {
                type: "category",
                gridIndex: 1,
                name: "App",
                boundaryGap: false,
                axisLabel: { rotate: 50, interval: 0 },
              },
              {
                type: "value",
                gridIndex: 2,
                name: "Reviews",
                axisLabel: { rotate: 50, interval: 0 },
              },
              {
                type: "value",
                gridIndex: 3,
                name: "Size",
                axisLabel: { rotate: 50, interval: 0 },
              },
            ],
            yAxis: [
              { type: "value", gridIndex: 0, name: "rating" },
              { type: "category", gridIndex: 1, name: "Category" },
              { type: "value", gridIndex: 2, name: "Installs" },
              { type: "value", gridIndex: 3, name: "Installs" },
            ],
            dataset: {
              dimensions: [
                "App",
                "Category",
                "Rating",
                "Reviews",
                "Size",
                "Installs",
                "Type",
                "Price",
                "Content Rating",
                "Genres",
                "Last Updated",
                "Current Ver",
                "Android Ver",
              ],
              source: data,
            },
            series: [
              {
                type: "scatter3D",
                symbolSize: "Size",
                encode: {
                  x: "Rating",
                  y: "Reviews",
                  z: "Installs",
                  tooltip: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                },
              },

              {
                type: "scatter",
                symbolSize: symbolSize,
                xAxisIndex: 0,
                yAxisIndex: 0,
                encode: {
                  x: "App",
                  y: "rating",
                  tooltip: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                },
              },
              {
                type: "scatter",
                symbolSize: symbolSize,
                xAxisIndex: 1,
                yAxisIndex: 1,
                encode: {
                  x: "App",
                  y: "Category",
                  tooltip: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                },
              },
              {
                type: "scatter",
                symbolSize: symbolSize,
                xAxisIndex: 2,
                yAxisIndex: 2,
                encode: {
                  x: "Reviews",
                  y: "Installs",
                  tooltip: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                },
              },
              {
                type: "scatter",
                symbolSize: symbolSize,
                xAxisIndex: 3,
                yAxisIndex: 3,
                encode: {
                  x: "Size",
                  y: "Installs",
                  tooltip: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                },
              },
            ],
          };

          console.log(option);
          console.log(dom);
          console.log(myChart);

          myChart.setOption(option);
        },
      });

      // if (option && typeof option === "object") {
      //   myChart.setOption(option);
      // }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the code running, the browser reports the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProgressive' of undefined
    at echarts.min.js:45
    at e.<anonymous> (echarts.min.js:45)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at P (echarts.min.js:35)
    at e.eachSeries (echarts.min.js:45)
    at t.restorePipelines (echarts.min.js:45)
    at Zv (echarts.min.js:45)
    at e.setOption (echarts.min.js:45)
    at Object.success (scatter.html:162)
    at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
```

All the items I logged out seem right.

It looks like the error went from:

```
myChart.setOption(option);
```

Why is this error reported and how can I fix it?

Comment: My blind guess would be, `var dom = document.getElementById("container");` is returning `null`. There's not really enough info here to really gather anything from the trace or error message

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I added `console.log(dom)` after `var dom = document.getElementById("container");` and successfully printed it out. I have edited the question and posted all the source code, will this help to find the cause of the error?

Comment: What is inside google_store.json file?

Comment: some json data, i mocked it using postman and changed the ajax get: https://b565a3a9-9a56-458a-97cd-273fbcb46dfe.mock.pstmn.io/data

Comment: echarts is looking for a datatype you're not providing in the correct format. Using apis, even if you do everything correctly on the front end, you might get weird errors back. Try to trap that fail, and repost the question if needed.

Comment: thank you for suggestion！i changed the format and that helped a lot. @wahwahwah

Comment: The problem is that, I used the 3D scatter of eharts but didn't import echart-gl. After adding `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts-gl/dist/echarts-gl.min.js"></script>` into my code, it doesn't go wrong any more.

Comment: @Azphire I'm glad you found the solution. You can [post and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank you.